An exercise about abelian Kummer extensions
I'm trying to do this problem about abelian Kummer extensions:

Image transcript and my attempts are below:
Let $K/F$ be a Galois extension with Galois group $G=\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)$ of order $n$. Assume that $G$ is abelian, that $F$ contains a primitive $n^\text{th}$ root of unity $ζ$, and that the characteristic of $F$ doesn't divide $n$. Let $\widehat{G}$ denote the set of group homomorphisms from $G$ to $F^{×}$, and for each $χ ∈ \widehat{G}$, define
$$
K_χ≔\{x ∈ K: g(x)=χ(g)x \text{ for all } g ∈ G\} .
$$
(a) Show that $\widehat{G}$ forms an abelian group under pointwise multiplication.
By Set of Homomorphisms between two abelian groups is a group $\widehat{G}$ forms a group under pointwise multiplication.
For $χ, ψ ∈ \widehat{G}$, to show that $χψ=ψχ$:
$$
(χψ)(g)=χ(g) ψ(g)=ψ(g) χ(g)=(ψχ)(g) \text{ for all } g ∈ G
$$

(b) Use the structure theorem for finite abelian groups to show that $\widehat{G}$ is isomorphic to $G$.
By the structure theorem, $G≅C_{n_1}×⋯×C_{n_r}$ for some integers $n_1, ⋯, n_r>1$ with $n_1|⋯|n_r$. Let $g_i$ be a generator for $C_{n_i}$ inside $G$.
Since $g_i^{n_i}=1$ and $χ$ is a group homomorphism, $χ(g_i)^{n_i}=1$, so $χ(g_i)=ζ^{\frac{n}{n_i}k_i}$ for some $k_i∈\{0,…,n_i-1\}$.
For $χ∈\widehat{G}$, define $f:\widehat{G}→C_{n_1}×⋯×C_{n_r}$ by $f(χ)=(k_1,…,k_n)$.
$f$ is a group homomorphism: let $ψ∈G,f(ψ)=(k_1',…,k_r')$, then $(ψχ)(g_i)=ψ(g_i)χ(g_i)=ζ^{\frac{n}{n_i}k_i}ζ^{\frac{n}{n_i}k_i'}=ζ^{\frac{n}{n_i}(k_i+k_i')}$, so $f(χψ)=(k_1+k_1',…,k_r+k_r')=f(χ)+f(ψ)$.
$f$ is injective: If $f(χ)=f(ψ)$, then $χ(g_i)=ψ(g_i)$ for all $i=1,…,r$, so $χ=ψ$.
$f$ is surjective: Let $(k_1,…,k_r)∈C_{n_1}×⋯×C_{n_r}$, define $χ∈\widehat{G}$ by $χ(g_i)=ζ^{\frac{n}{n_i}k_i}$, then $f(χ)=(k_1,…,k_r)$, so $f$ is an isomorphism.

(c) Show that if $χ, ψ ∈ \widehat{G}$ and $x ∈ K_χ, y ∈ K_ψ$, then $x y ∈ K_{χ ψ}$.
For $g∈G$, $g(xy)=g(x)g(y)=χ(g)xψ(g)y=(χψ)(g)xy$, so $xy∈K_{χψ}$.

(d) Let $χ ∈ \widehat{G}$ and $x ∈ K$. Show that $e_χ(x)≔\frac{1}{n} \sum_{g ∈ G} χ\left(g^{-1}\right) g(x)$ is an element of $K_χ$.
For all $h∈G$,
\begin{align*}
h(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{g ∈ G} χ\left(g^{-1}\right) g(x))
&=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{g ∈ G} χ\left(g^{-1}\right) h(g(x))\\
\text{let }hg=g'&\\
&=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{g' ∈ G} χ\left(g'^{-1}h\right) g'(x)\\
&=χ(h)⋅\frac{1}{n} \sum_{g' ∈ G} χ\left(g'^{-1}\right) g'(x)
\end{align*}
so $e_χ(x)∈K_χ$.

(e) Suppose that $G=⟨g⟩$ is cyclic and let $χ: G → F^{×}$ be the unique group homomorphism sending $g$ to $ζ$. Show that $e_χ(x) ≠ 0$ for at least one $x ∈ K$.
Since distinct automorphisms $g$ of a field $K$ are linearly independent as functions on $K$, $e_χ(x) ≠ 0$ for at least one $x ∈ K$.

(f) Deduce that there exist $u_1, ⋯, u_r ∈ K$ and positive integers $n_1, ⋯, n_r$ such that $K=F(u_1, ⋯, u_r)$ and $u_i^{n_i} ∈ F$ for all $i=1, ⋯, r$.
By (b) let $χ_i$ be a generator of the factor $C_{n_i}$ of $\widehat{G}$, so $χ_i(g_i)=ζ^{\frac{n}{n_i}};χ_i(g_j)=1$ for all $j≠i$.
Apply (e) to each $χ_i$, there is $u_i ∈ K$ such that $e_{χ_i}(u_i) ≠ 0$, by (d) $u_i ∈ K_{χ_i}$, so $g(u_i)=χ_i(g)u_i$ for all $g ∈ G$.
By (c), $u_i^{n_i} ∈ K_{χ_i^{n_i}}=K_{1_{\widehat{G}}}=\{x ∈ K: g(x)=x \text{ for all } g ∈ G\}=F$.
To show that $K=F(u_1, ⋯, u_r)$, it suffices to show $[F(u_1, ⋯, u_r):F]=n$.
For $1≤k≤n_1$,
$g_1^k(u_1)=χ_1(g_1^k)u_1=ζ^{\frac{n}{n_1}k}u_1$ are distinct roots of $m_{F,u_1}(t)$, so $\deg(m_{F,u_1})≥n_1$, but $u_1^{n_1}∈F$, so $n_1=\deg(m_{F,u_1})=[F(u_1):F]$.
I don't know how to finish part (f). Can someone help me with it? Thanks!

Since your group $G$ is cyclic, you should use the fundamental theorem of Galois Theory to induct on the factors $G_i$ successively. Then I believe you are done just by comparing degrees?

@Yaneda Thanks. How to show $[F(u_1,\dots,u_i,u_{i+1}):F(u_1,\dots,u_i)]=n_{i+1}$?


I don't know how to finish part (f).

To show that $K=F(u_1, ⋯, u_r)$, it suffices to show $\operatorname{Gal}(K/F(u_1, ⋯, u_r))$ is trivial.
Suppose $g∈G$ fixes $u_1, ⋯, u_r$, then $g(u_i)=u_i$, so $χ_i(g)=1$ for all $i=1, ⋯, r$, so $g=1_G$.
